# Apps Script Export GUI?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm deciding whether to build a UI using the UI Builder or just coding it.

The UI Builder seems like a quick way, but does it allow you to export the code so you can share it with someone else? From what I've seen, there is no option to do that.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not allow you to export from the UI editor.  This is one major reason I've chosen not to use it.  I can't have dev/pre-prod/prod type environments when working toward deployment.

I've also found the UI editor to be much better at static sized layouts where I prefer to build mine where they will expand dynamically.

Comment: Just to corroborate. I have the same opinion/experience.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that I don;ole about using the UI Builder is that not all the controls are available.  For example, I needed to add a DateBox so I had to change the layout of the form so that it would appears as the last control (It belongs in a FlowPanel)

Answer (score 0):

There is one way how to export UI from Apps Script GUI Builder - share whole document with somebody and he can make the copy of the document including your UI.

But I agree with @mzimmerman it isn't usable in bigger projects. I use it only in some small prototyping cases.

Comment: I do agree with most of the point explained here but I'd like to add one use case that is when the elements of the UI have to be positioned   on an unregular pattern such as a map or a picture... in this case the graphic interface is VERY easy and useful. See [this example](https://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=AKfycbyc2SWv6JhDgUpXwF7aAARihIE7WPRmrQf6KIOtfQ) for instance, it would have been quite hard to design with code, I made it in just a couple of hours from scratch (the UI, not the code behind ;-))  Also, it is always possible and easy to mix both techniques.